# .NET cookie-based authentication without forms authentication

Tags: authentication, cookies

Is there library out in the .NET world that would allow me to place a secure cookie on the clients browser?

I have a subsection of a website that needs its own authentication that doesn't interfere at all with the built in authentication mechanisms in .NET. For example, when logging into the subsection, the Request.Identity.Name, etc, must remain untouched.

I could just role my own functions that place cookies and read them, but I am not sure if there is any security concerns I should be aware of, and if there are, is there a library out there that will help me keep my cookie secure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not piggyback on Forms Authentication to implement this, since you are already using it for the rest of the website?

If a user successfully "logs in" to the subsection of the website, set a session variable indicating that they now have access to the special area.  Check that session variable to control access.

Comment: This subsection is supposed to be able to be used in any application. The application it is dropped into can't know anything about the subsection. That is why the it can't piggy back because this it may break the "unknown application" the subsection is residing in.